# React Query is not cathcing Axios error in React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native, axios, expo, react-query

I have a react native expo typescript project and I'm doing authentication. I have axios function:

```
export type LoginData = {
    email: string;
    password: string;
}

export const loggInUser = async (data: LoginData): Promise<User> => {
    const response = await axiosClient.post<Promise<User>>('/login', data);
    return response.data;    
}
```

And inside my Login component I have:

```
 const { 
        mutate: loginUser, isLoading
     } = useMutation(
        (userData: LoginData) => loggInUser(userData),
        {
            onSuccess: (data) => {
                stateLoggIn(data);
            },
            onError(error: any) {     
                setErrorMsg((error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.message) || error.message || error.toString());
            }
        }   
    );
```

When the axios promise returns error, for instance 400, I am shown a react native warning for uncatched error. I tried to implement tryCatch inside axios function but then my onError case inside mutation wont ever fire off.

[image]

This is the react native expo warning